# Wrong button size

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have DialogFragment layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:background="@color/white"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingTop="21dp"
android:paddingLeft="24dp"
android:paddingRight="8dp"
android:paddingBottom="8dp"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
    android:text="@string/lbl_why_go_away"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/whyGoAwayCaption"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="@dimen/fontHuge"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
    android:layout_weight="0" />
<ListView
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
    android:id="@+id/reasonsList" />
<EditText
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="108dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
    android:gravity="top|left"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/cancel_dialog_your_reason_bg"
    android:hint="@string/ph_your_reason"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:id="@+id/otherReasonEditText" />
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right">
    <Button
        android:background="#CCCCCC"
        android:text="@string/btn_return"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/primaryRed"
        android:drawablePadding="0dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:paddingLeft="9dp"
        android:paddingRight="9dp"
        android:paddingTop="9dp"
        android:paddingBottom="9dp"
        android:id="@+id/returnButton" />
  <Button
        android:background="#CCCCCC"
        android:text="@string/btn_ready"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="9dp"
        android:paddingRight="9dp"
        android:paddingTop="9dp"
        android:paddingBottom="9dp"
        android:drawablePadding="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:textColor="@color/primaryRed"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:id="@+id/readyButton" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This looks like this (Android 4.2 Galaxy S4):

[image]

Problem with buttons size. They should have just padding 8dp around text and nothing else, but they are much bigger then text size. If i set background to `@android:color/transparent` view is the same. Tell me, what's wrong?

PS: Here's right view (screenshot from preview in VisualStudio)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Button has a fixed size. u can't change it. U can make it bigger but can't make it small. As u are using dialog u can use textview instead of button. them do operation with textview. if u want to give a button like shape u can use a LinearLayout and make that layout in a shape ...

Comment: Bad and strange news. But your solution works! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

change your buttons to this pls

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/returnButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:background="#CCCCCC"
    android:drawablePadding="0dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="9dp"
    android:text="text" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/readyButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:background="#CCCCCC"
    android:drawablePadding="0dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="9dp"
    android:text="text" />
```

Comment: Nope. My screen was not correct enough, so i changed it. My problem is right padding. As you can see, left padding is correct, but right is much bigger than i need. Top and bottom paddings are not the same as left, but it is not so important.

Comment: @Nikita Leshchev: i edited my answer, change your byttons with mine